# send mail with phpmailer + ajax (with a php file already included)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm about to make my first ajax function ever but beforehand I have a question I couldn't find an answer for.

The contact form on my website is accessible on every page (in the website's footer), I want to use ajax to trigger phpmailer so the page doesn't need to refresh and the navigation isn't interrupted.

On top of my page I have included my functions library :

```
<?php
    require_once('functions.php');

    $app = new action();
    $app->init();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This `function.php` file, also present in every page, already has a working mail function

```
public static function sendMail($mail, $name, $subject, $body) {
 // stuff to send the mail with phpmailer
}
```

From what I understand, to send a mail with ajax and phpmailer, I need to handle the inputs informations with JQuery then use ajax to send the data to a php file containing the phpmailer function.

My question is : can I send the informations to my `functions.php` file instead of a dedicated one for this ajax function ? Is it possible (even tho it is included in my page) ?
Is this a good idea or is there any cons of doing so (if it is possible )

I was wondering this because I can't see the need to create a new php file for a function I already have included in my page anyways.

Apologies if the title/explanation seems sloppy, I am lacking some ajax vocabulary.

Comment: If you are wanting to use jquery/ajax and utilize your existing sendMail function you can, you will just need to make sure that your function can handle the post request coming from your newly created ajax call. There is no need to create a whole new php file.

Comment: thank you, so, the fact that the function I am using in a file that is already included inmy page won't be problem right ? (my existing mail function is in `functions.php` which I include in every page

Comment: Correct. You will just need to add something in your functions file (or whichever file you are going to call from your ajax call) to recognize the post request and call the sendMail function.